# Plotting a 2D mesh grid with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a 2D discretization rectangular mesh with non-regular
x y axes values, e.g. the typical discretization meshes used in CFD.
An example of the code may be:

```
    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,8))

    axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size':17})

    axes.set_xticks(self.xPoints)
    axes.set_yticks(self.yPoints)

    plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

    myName = "2D.jpg" 

    fig.savefig(myName)
```

where self.xPoints and self.yPoints are 1D non-regular vectors.

This piece of code produce a good discretization mesh, **the problem are the 
xtics and ytics labels** because they appear for all values of xPoints and yPoints (they overlap). 
How can I easily redefine the printed values in the axes? 
Let's say I only want to show the minimum and maximum value for x and y and not all values from the discretization mesh.
I cann't post a example-figure because it is the first time I ask something here (I can send it by mail if requested)

Comment: did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you explicitly told matplotlib to label each point when you wrote:

```
axes.set_xticks(self.xPoints)
axes.set_yticks(self.yPoints)
```

comment out those lines and see what the result looks like.

Of course, if you only want the first and last point labelled, it becomes:

```
axes.set_xticks([self.xPoints[0], self.xPoints[-1]])
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However if I comment set_xticks and set_yticks nothing is printed because I'm using the xticks to show the discrectized mesh.

Answer (score 0):

If the gridline was specified by `axes.set_xticks()`, I don't think it would be possible to show ticks without overlap in your case.

I may have a solution for you:

```
...

ax = plt.gca()

#Arr_y: y-direction data, 1D numpy array or list.
for j in range(len(Arr_y)):
    plt.hline(y = Arr_y[j], xmin = Arr_x.min(), xmax = Arr_x.max(), color = 'black')

#Arr_x: x-direction data, 1D numpy array or list.
for i in range(len(Arr_x)):
    plt.vline(x = Arr_x[i], ymin = Arr_y.min(), ymax = Arr_y.max(), color = 'black')

#Custom your ticks here, 1D numpy array or list.
ax.set_xticks(Arr_xticks)
ax.set_yticks(Arr_yticks)

plt.xlim(Arr_x.min(), Arr_x.max())
plt.ylim(Arr_y.min(), Arr_y.max())

plt.show()
...
```

`hlines` and `vlines` are horizontal and vertical lines, you can specify those lines with boundary data in both x and y directions.

I tried it with 60×182 non uniform mesh grid which cost me 1.2s, hope I can post a picture here.